# Show numerals only on clicking edit text and also able to accept decimal point(.)

Tags: android

For an edittext i used  wt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);  But the virtual keyboard that comes up on clicking that field is not showing integers only. It is showing normal querty keypad only.  But when i used like this wt.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY); the keypad is showing as desired but am not able to use the decimal point(.). I wanted to get the numerical keypad as well as able to enter decimal point. How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wt.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(false,true));
```

where wt is your EditText if I got that right.
This will force the EditText to accept digits + points and commas.